# Debian server unique identificator via php

Tags: php, linux, shell, debian, hardware

i am wondering is there a way to obtain some unique debian server (not user) identificator via php? Server is mine and i want my code runs only on that serwer. So i have to find some identificator on debian like hdd serial/number , motherboard s/n , cpu s/n etc. yhat i can get through php. So even if the software will be copied (althought it is ciphered) it cant work on any hardware but mine.

Thanks, Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, the MAC address (a unique identifier of the network hardware) is used to identify a server and to validate the software license. Unfortunately, you can't access the MAC address directly using PHP, but you can parse the output of the unix command `system("netstat -ie", $output);`.

Answer (score 0):

To complete topic

```
<?php
system("netstat -ie");
$content=ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();

$needle= "HWaddr";
$pos = strpos($content, $needle);
$macp=substr($content,($pos+7),17);
echo $mac;

?>
```